# How to allow search using CONTAINS on 'B&B' without getting the prompt for 'Enter Substitution Variable' because of the & and get only 'B&B'

Tags: oracle, contains

I am performing a search of a CLOB that is Globally indexed so I can use a CONTAINS function.  The phrase I am searching for is 'B&B'.  I have tried multiple ways to escape the & so it won't be looked at as a prompt for user input.  I am unable to do it.

```
select * from table where contains(txt, '({B&B})')>0;--this gives me substitution variable prompt

select * from table where contains(txt, '({B}{&}{B})')>0;--this finds 'B B'

select * from table where contains(txt, '(B{&}B)')>0;--this finds 'B B'

select * from table where contains(txt, '({B&B})')>0;--this gives me substitution variable prompt

select * from table where contains(txt, '({B&}B)')>0;--this finds 'B B', 'B.B', 'B&B'

select * from table where contains(txt,'NEAR (({B&},(B)),1)') > 0;--this finds 'B B', 'B.B', 'B&B'

select * from table where txt like '%B&B%';--this gives me substitution variable prompt
```

I can't deactivate the ability to use substitution variable prompt, so this must be done in code.

I need to ignore all occurrences of 'B B', 'B.B'  and have it return only the rows that have 'B&B' in this field.

Comment: What SQL IDE are you using?  Every tool has a different way to disable substitution variables.  Littlefoot's answer works for SQL*Plus.  In some IDEs two ampersands will escape substitution variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, it is a CLOB. Would `INSTR` do any good, anyway?

```
SQL> create table test (txt clob);

Table created.

SQL> set define off
SQL> insert into test
  2    select 'This is an example which does not contain BB, B B, B.B' from dual union all
  3    select 'Query should return B&B because it is here' from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> select txt
  2  from test
  3  where instr(txt, 'B&B') > 0;

TXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Query should return B&B because it is here

SQL>
```

Comment: INSTR absolutely worked, but only after I ran set define off.  

I am using SQL Developer, but the code that ultimately runs is from a shell script that shoots off multiple SQL scripts and PL/SQL packages.  

Doubling up on && didn't work.  

THANKS SO MUCH!!

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad if it helped (by the way, I guess you saw the 2nd statement I ran, it is `set define off`. If you don't do that, `&` *calls* for a substitution variable input).

Comment: It is just really strange.  We seem to have code that searches for things with an & in it  here and there and they seem to not have any issues (or do they?), but testing this one is the first it gave me real issues and I had to use 'set define off' in order to even test it.  Go figure.  Thanks again!